# Are lattices in the special real linear group subgroup seperable?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, lattices, geometric-group-theory

Let $G \leq SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ be a lattice, let $H \leq G$ be a finitely generated subgroup of infinite index, and let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Must there be some $H \leq U \leq G$ such that $n \leq [G : U] < \infty$ ?

Comment: What you ask in the question is weaker than LERF, namely whether the profinite closure of every f.g. subgroup of infinite index has infinite index. The answer is yes, surface groups are LERF by a theorem of Peter Scott. See e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.5135

Comment: @YCor: It seems to me that you just provided a perfectly fine answer. Why did you choose to put it as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: @YCor I am aware of Scott's theorem and of the fact that my condition is weaker. There is probably a problem with my geometry. Why do you say that these groups are surface groups? What definition of surface groups do you use?

Comment: @Pablo are you worried about torsion, or about $SL$ vs $PSL?$

Comment: @IgorRivin no I am not worried about that, but I seem not to understand the definition of a surface group. I recall it as something with a presentation with a product of commutators but this is probably the case of a compact surface. What is the exact definition of a surface group?

Comment: For your purposes, a torsion-free lattice in $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ is the best definition.

Comment: @Pablo: LERF is (trivially) a commensurability invariant and stable under taking subgroups. Therefore if you know that usual surface groups ($\pi_1$ of closed orientable surfaces) are LERF, you know for all lattices in $SL_2(\mathbf{R})$, including those with torsion.

Comment: @IgorRivin thanks for explaining. So for this purpose I understand, but in general: Can you give a reference for a definition of a surface group?

Comment: @Pablo: the definition I gave is one of the definitions, which are equivalent from the classification of surfaces (which gives presentations for fundamental groups of surfaces of finite type) and the uniformization theorem (which tells us that (almost all) surfaces correspond to lattices in $Isom(H^2).$

Comment: @YCor and if I take $SL_3(\mathbb{R})$ how things change in this case? For example, if $G = SL_3(\mathbb{Z})$ does the weaker condition I have asked about holds?

Comment: Yes it dramatically changes. By Weisfeiler, any Zariski-dense subgroup of $SL_3(\mathbf{Z})$ is has finite index closure for the pro-congruence topology, which coincides with the profinite topology by Bass-Milnor-Serre. By Margulis-Soifer, there are Zariski-dense subgroups of infinite index.

Comment: @YCor but we need the Zariski dense subgroup to be finitely generated. What does Margulis-Soifer say? It gives a finitely generated one?

Comment: @Pablo: in char 0 any Zariski dense subgroup contains a f.g. Zariski dense subgroup.

Comment: @YCor Why so? Is this trivial?

Comment: Two random long (in terms of generators) words in a Zariski dense subgroup generate a Zariski dense subgroup (yours truly, IMRN 2011, I think). The weaker statement is due to Tits (his paper on the Tits alternative)

Comment: @Pablo it follows from the 1-generator version of the Tits alternative, due to Burnside. But you don't need this, since Margulis-Soifer directly construct a finitely generated free Zariski dense subgroup.